# Why doesn't before_filter work the way I expect with restful-authentication?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, inheritance, oop

My application controller looks like this

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  include AuthenticatedSystem
  helper :all # include all helpers, all the time
  protect_from_forgery # :secret => 'sup3rs3cr3t'
  filter_parameter_logging :password

  # Here's the interesting bit
  before_filter :login_required, :except => [:index, :show, :new]
end
```

Now I have another controller that looks like this

```
class CompletelySecretController < ApplicationController

  # the other interesting bit
  before_filter :login_required
  def index
    @secrets = Secret.find(:all)
  end
end
```

I can still see all of the secrets, despite me stating that a login is required for all actions with

`before_filter :login_required`

Is it not intuitive to think that the `before_filter` in the child class overrides the `before_filter` in the parent class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`before_filter` in your subclass doesn't override the same call in the super class, but they stack after each other instead. It is how the chain of filters work. If you want to skip the filter added in your ApplicationController, you can use `skip_before_filter` method - see "Filter Chain Skipping" section [here in the filters documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Filters/ClassMethods.html).